# What's the proper phrase for "退一万步说(back-stepping ten thousand steps)" in English

Tags: phrase-request

The phrase "退一万步说(back-stepping ten thousand steps, or taking ten thousand steps back)" is normally used for stressing that the gap between the two sides are so wide, or the topics in discussion is so broad, that *even if I withdraw from my current standpoint, back-stepping ten thousand steps, getting back to the very fundamental and core of the discussion*, that's what expression is trying to convey. I.e., it basically means *"even if"*, but there is so much connotation within such *"even if"*. One example,

> **退一万步说**，假如说这件事是真的，难道不好吗

Basically trying to say *"**Even if** it is true, what's so bad about it"*, when the discussion was on the basis that it is not true.

One meaning of it is *"the bottom line is"*, but It usually means *"even if"*, *"however"*, *"anyway"*, *"anyhow"*, or *"taking a step back"* but trying to emphasis that the compromising is a thousand times stronger --

- "妥協別人的論點，退一萬步就是讓到極限了", It tries to emphasis that ***even if*** I try to compromise, to the extreme point that I  can, that I cannot compromise any steps further.
- "這樣一步一步條分縷析對方論點的不合理處，以至萬步", It is used to stress that the demand from the other side is so unreasonable, that even if I backtrack step by step, until ten thousand steps, the asking still doesn't make sense.

> **退一万步说**，就算我真的知道了没告诉你，我也没错阿

*Even supposed that I knew and I didn't tell you in time, you really can't blame me on that either.*

So, is there any English idiom that is close to this? Thanks.

Comment: Even if I bend over backwards, I cannot understand your point.

Comment: The two opposing parties are ***poles apart***

Comment: No, no, a thousand times no!